# How does this limit by sierpinski work?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, irrational-numbers

In the book mathematical analysis by S K Chatterjea (2nd edition) this limit is mentioned on page 72. [image: picture of book]

For integers $x$,
$$kx - [kx] = 0 $$ hence $$l = 0$$.

For irrationals,
if we except the difference (i.e, $kx - [kx]$) to be random. then the average value would be 0.5 as the difference lies between 0 and 1. thus $l = 0.5$.

for rationals, we could assume it to random but the difference is 0 every time $q$ divides $k$ , hence its average value would be less than 0.5

This sounds plausible but how we prove it?

I couldn't locate any sources online. i would be grateful to if someone could point me to any references. Does this limit have some name and has been studied in literature?

Comment: I think people are downvoting you because you haven't told us what you've tried. If you give more detail or at least tell us your thought process folks should be more responsive

Comment: Thank you. I will edit the question.

Comment: FYI, I believe the relevant Sierpiński papers are [*Un théorème sur les nombres irrationnels*](https://www.google.com/search?q=Sierpinski+%22Un+theoreme+sur+les+nombres+irrationnels%22&filter=0) ([this google-books search also](https://www.google.com/search?q=Sierpinski+%22Un+theoreme+sur+les+nombres+irrationnels%22&tbm=bks)), which is a shorter French summary paper **(continued)**

Comment: of the more detailed Polish original version [*Pewne twierdzenie o liczbach niewymiernych*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22Pewne+twierdzenie+o+liczbach+niewymiernych%22&filter=0) ([this google-books search also](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22Pewne+twierdzenie+o+liczbach+niewymiernych%22&tbm=bks)). Both papers were published in 1909.

Comment: i will check them out, thanks

Comment: If $x=\frac pq$ in lowest terms, then every $q$ consecutive summands will equal $\{0,\frac1q,\dots,\frac{q-1}q\}$ in some order. The limit will therefore equal the average of these $q$ quantities, which can be calculated exactly using the formula for the sum of an arithmetic progression.